# HTML CSS: how horizontally center browser modal window containing iframe?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a modal window to play a video file. For `modal-body` widths less than about 500 px; the modal window appears centered horizontally, but above that, it grows to the right, so that by 900px, it's falling off the window on the right side. Any way to fix that? The video is always perfectly framed by the modal window, it's just the modal window whose left-to-right I can't get centered.

Also, I'd like to set the `modal-body`max-width property to prevent it growing above a certain size, but be responsive to the browser window below that size. Is this possible?

Normally I'd use Bootstrap 3.3.6 `embed-responsive-16by9` to get a responsive solution, but this only works with 16x9 aspect ratios, and the videos I'm showing are an odd-ball aspect ratio. Not sure how else to do it.

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px;">
                <div align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 0; 
                                    padding-bottom: 64.5%; position: relative; margin: 0px; 
                                    padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0 px;">
                    <iframe style="position: absolute;
                                   top: 0; left: 0;
                                   width: 100%; height: 100%; 
                                   margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" 
                                   src="" frameborder="0" 
                                   allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error, I find the following works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. It gives a responsive modal window to show youtube videos of any arbitrary aspect ratio. The width of the modal window does not grow larger than 969px even if the window has room. I would appreciate any comments whether I can expect this to work for any modern browser.

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" 
         style="width: 100%; max-width: 969px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px;">
                <div align="center" 
                     style="width: 100%; height: 0; 
                            padding-bottom: 64.5%; 
                            position: relative;">
                    <iframe style="position: absolute; 
                                   top: 0;
                                   left: 0;
                                   width: 100%; 
                                   height: 100%;" 
                         src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="width: 900px; margin: auto; padding: 0px;bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; top: 0; position: absolute; display: table">
                <div align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 0;
                                    padding-bottom: 64.5%; position: relative; margin: 0px; 
                                    padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0 px;
                                    ">
                    <iframe style="position: absolute;
                                   top: 0; left: 0;
                                   width: 100%; height: 100%; 
                                   margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" 
                                   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6YDQRo227hU" frameborder="0" 
                                   allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this code not woking on firefox, because modal-body with style display: table not make height of it fit content

Add below script to make it working on all browsers:

```
var mds = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-body");
for (var i = 0; i < mds.length; i++) {
    mds[i].style.height = mds[i].children[0].offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I need it to work on all modern browsers.

Comment: Ok. We can add script to set height for .modal-body to make it working on all browsers

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any change in results compared to the original posted code.